# The sequence $f_n(x) =f(x^n)$ belongs to $L^1([0,1])$ if $f \in L^1([0,1])$ and is continuous at $0.$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous at $0.$ If $f \in L^1([0,1])$ then i want to prove that for every $n \in \mathbb{N},$ $f_n(x) =f(x^n) \in L^1([0,1]). $

Comment: What happens if you try to use the change-of-variables formula to check that $f(x^n)$ is in $L^1$?

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is bounded by some $M>0$ in an interval of the form $[0,\varepsilon)$. So, if $n\in\mathbb N$, $$\int_0^1|f_n(x)|\,dx=\int_0^{\varepsilon^{1/n}}|f(x^n)|\,dx+\int_{\varepsilon^{1/n}}^1|f(x^n)|\,dx\leq\int_0^{\varepsilon^{1/n}}M\,dx+\int_{\varepsilon}^1|f(y)|\frac{1}{n}y^{1/n-1}\,dy=$$$$M\varepsilon^{1/n}+\frac{1}{n}\int_{\varepsilon}^1\frac{|f(y)|}{y^{1/n-1}}\,dy\leq M\varepsilon^{1/n}+\frac{\varepsilon^{1-1/n}}{n}\int_{\varepsilon}^1|f(y)\,dy\leq M\varepsilon^{1/n}+\frac{\varepsilon^{1-1/n}}{n}\|f\|_1<\infty.$$ So, $f_n$ is in $L^1$.